# Converging Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I show that the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ defined by $$x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n(x_{n}^2 + 3a)}{3x_{n}^2 + a}$$ is convergent? I don't think plugging this into the convergent-sequences definition will help and i've been stuck on this for awhile. Someone suggested cauchy criterion, but I don't know how to apply that.

Apologies, I forgot to include that $a>0$, $x_1 > 0$.

Comment: Can't you show that this is bounded and monotonic?

Comment: What is $x_0$? If $x_0=0$, then $x_n=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: It might be convenient to study the function $f(t)=\frac{t(t^2+3a)}{3t^2+a}$ (calculate the derivative to find where it's increasing etc.) and then apply the results to the sequence like @Heisenberg suggests.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to include that $a>0$, $x_1 > 0$.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I'll attempt that.

Comment: $\pm\,\sqrt{\, a\,}\,$ satisfies the recurrence.

Comment: Once you prove it converges (if it does), you can solve: $$L = \frac{L(L^2+3a)}{3L^2+a}.$$

Comment: You can assume it converges to a value $> 0$. Then, you'll find that your assumption is consistent when you find that it converges to $\sqrt{\,a\,}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin So the derivative of $f(t) = \frac{t(t^2 + 3a)}{3t^2 +a}$ is $f'(t) = \frac{3(a-t^2)^2}{(a+3t^2)^2}$. Root is $\sqrt{a}$. But we have only showed that it is monotonically increasing. Not boundedness. Why do we care about the $\sqrt{a}$? I'm hoping someone will actually provide an Answer soon instead of a comment.

Comment: In the meantime, comments are always allowed.

Comment: Indeed they are. I do not want to repast my question I asked Julian in his answer in this comment section for redundancy sake. @FelixMarin What do you think about applying the Caucy Criterion method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_convergence_test ?

Answer (score 1):

Working from the defining equation
$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n(x_n^2+3a)}{3x_n^2+a}\tag{1}
$$
we have
$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{2x_n(\sqrt{a}+x_n)}{3x_n^2+a}\sqrt{a}+\frac{(x_n-\sqrt{a})^2}{3x_n^2+a}x_n\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
\frac{2x_n(\sqrt{a}+x_n)}{3x_n^2+a}+\frac{(x_n-\sqrt{a})^2}{3x_n^2+a}=1\tag{3}
$$
Since both $\frac{2x_n(\sqrt{a}+x_n)}{3x_n^2+a}$ and $\frac{(x_n-\sqrt{a})^2}{3x_n^2+a}$ are at least $0$, Equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ say that $x_{n+1}$ is between $x_n$ and $\sqrt{a}$ (inclusive). This is enough to guarantee convergence (if $x_1\le\sqrt{a}$, then $x_n$ is non-decreasing and bounded above by $\sqrt{a}$; if $x_1\ge\sqrt{a}$, then $x_n$ is non-increasing and bounded below by $\sqrt{a}$).

To find the limit, subtract $x_n$ from $(2)$ and take the limit as $n\to\infty$:
$$
0=\frac{2x_\infty(\sqrt{a}+x_\infty)}{3x_\infty^2+a}(\sqrt{a}-x_\infty)\tag{4}
$$
Since $x_\infty$ is between $x_1$ and $\sqrt{a}$ (inclusive), it must be greater than $0$. Therefore, we must have $x_\infty=\sqrt{a}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
f(x)=\frac{x(x^2+a)}{3\,x^2+a},\quad x\ge0.
$$
$f(x)=x$ has two non-negative solutions: $0$ and $\sqrt a$. Moreover
$$
x<f(x)<\sqrt a\quad\text{if}\quad 0<x<\sqrt a,
$$
and
$$
\sqrt a<f(x)<x\quad\text{if}\quad x>\sqrt a.
$$
[image: Graph of $f$ when $a=2$]

1. If $x=\sqrt a$ then $x_n=\sqrt a$ for all $n$.
2. If $0<x_1<\sqrt a$, then $x_n$ is increasing and bounded above by $\sqrt a$. This implies that it converges, and the limit must be $\sqrt a$.
3. If $x_1>\sqrt a$, then $x_n$ is decreasing and bounded below by $\sqrt a$. This implies that it converges, and the limit must be $\sqrt a$.

Comment: Julian, first thank you for such a detailed reply. Second, and I think this is question whose answer is staring in my face, why are we allowed to study the function $f(x) = \frac{x(x^2 + 3a)}{3x^2 + a}$ instead of what we originally have? That is, $x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n(x_{n}^{2} + 3a)}{3x_{n}^{2} + a}$ where $x_{n}$'s are sequences. ALSO - why are we solving $f(x)=x$ if we originally have $x_{\mathbf{n+1}} = \cdots$?

Comment: It is clear where $f$ came from: changed $x_n$ by $x$. The sequence of iterates is now $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. **If** we know that $x_n$ converges to $\hat x$ and that $f$ is continuous, taking limits we get $f(\hat x)=\hat x$. This idea will work for most (but not all) problems of iterated sequences. Another way is to show by induction that $x_n$ is monotone and bounded. Using $f$ this follows easily from inequalities like $x<f(x)$: $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)<x_n$.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this for generic $a$ aand $x_0$, and the answer is that it does *not* converge for all values of $x_0$ if $a < 0$.

A tempting first transformation is to scale out $a$ by substituting $u = \frac{x^2}{a}$ giving
$$
u_{n+1} = u_n\left( \frac{u_n+3}{3u_n+1} \right)^2
$$
We immediately see that this converges for $u_0 \geq 0$, but when $u_0 < 0$ it goes chatic for most values of $u_0 < 0$, and has some 2-cycles which are unstable (for example, start with $$ u_0 = -0.527864045$$
which stays near an oscillation alternating with $-9.472136$ for about 10 oscilations before moving far enough away to get chaotic; there is a fixed point near there.

Comment: Interesting. Tangential, however, since the question says that $x_1\gt0$ and $a\gt0$. It might be an interesting project to find how the sequences behave for different $a\lt0$ and $x_1$.  Since $x_{n+1}/x_n$ is even, the sign of $x_1$ doesn't provide anything interesting.